# How to insert a new column in an excel workbook using xlwings library in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xlwings

I need to add a new empty column in between two columns of an existing excel using xlwings. How do I do that?

I need to use xlwings library itself as the project requirements need that library.

Please help me with the code

I am using this code :

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import DeleteShiftDirection
wb = xw.Book('input_file.xlsm')
wb.sheets['Sheet 1'].delete()
wb.sheets['Sheet 3'].delete()
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet 2']
sheet.range('1:1').api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp)
sheet.pictures[0].delete()
wb.sheets['Sheet 2'].range('I:I').insert()
wb.save('input_file.xlsm')
```

Comment: E,g at Col A; wb.sheets[0].range('A:A').insert(). See https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.insert for more info if needed

Answer (score 2):

As @moken already commented:

```
# import the lib
import xlwings as xw

# create a workbook
wb = xw.Book()

# for the first sheet (index 0) in range from A to A insert a column
wb.sheets[0].range('A:A').insert()
```

If you already have an xml file, you may open it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

# new dataframe
df = pd.read_xml("path.xml")
```

Then it is up to you how to manipulate with the data

Comment: But using this code, I am getting the AttributeError : 'range' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: @Prerna Gupta The code above is correct, would not raise an error. Post your code in your question.

Comment: @Prerna Gupta I had your code sample moved to your question. If you still need help as requested post the full (all lines) traceback error in your question as well.

Comment: I'm also getting some errors "ws.range('A:A').insert()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Range.insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'shift'"